# Is solving QP easier than a QCQP with linear objective?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, qcqp

Is solving a $QP$ (i.e.: quadratic program, hence a quadratic objective function with linear constraints) easier than solving a $QCQP$ (ie.: quadratic constrained quadratic problem) with linear objective?

I am aware that $QP \subseteq QCQP$ and that $QCQP$ is generally harder than $QP$.
Moreover, i am aware that a linear matrix is a special case of a quadratic matrix.
Consequently, a problem with linear objectives and quadratic constraints would lie in $QCQP$, but not in $QP$. On the other hand, it seems almost equivalent and my intuition is that it can not be harder to solve than a $QP$.

However, I am studying modern portfolio theory, where usually a (quadratic) variance term is optimized together with a (linear) return term. Among 2 famous reformulations, the variance can either enter the objectives or the constraints. However, for some reason i almost always see the quadratic term in the objective, even when this is not the most natural way to write the problem.

I am wondering wether this is merely convention or is there maybe some subtle computational advantage im missing.

So in summary i would like to ask:

How does the special case of a quadratic constrained quadratic problem with a linear objective function and a single quadratic constraint relate to a quadratic program? Is it equivalent or harder?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Bot: i think this is a clear question and cant understand why this is reported by the bot...

Comment: @ckrk it is reported by a bot, as it came from a review queue for first questions. The reviewer decided to share feedback they believed was necessary; however, it is listed as a comment by a bot.

Comment: I (personally) would suggest looking into formulating the question more clearly, to-the-point, and specifically about what you want to get from the answerers,

Comment: fwiw: I think this is a lovely question.

Comment: My research involved a QCQP and I solved the problem using the log barrier method, which requires the gradient and hessian of the constraints. If the constraints were linear, I imagine this would have made everything a lot easier (most of the computational effort was spent checking if I violated the constraints when computing a Newton step)

Comment: @AntonMenshov i have tried to summarize the question once more in an endit. Hopefully, this is clearer. However, if it is possible to get in touch with the reviewer i would be happy about a more specific critique, as im not very clear in howfar the question is flawed.

Comment: I think both QP (say min risk subject to return constraint) as QCP (say max return subject to risk constraint) models are nowadays solved as cone programming models. I looked at this a while ago. Continuous models (for my data set) were about the same speed. When I added binary variables (cardinality constrained portfolios), the MIQP was significantly faster than the MIQCP model  (maybe the MIP part is the cause of this, not the relaxations).

Comment: I guess the reason for MIQP being much faster than MIQCP is that the MIQP allows you to use a fast dual simplex to warm-start in nodes, while MIQCP is harder to warm-start being interior-point based.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg The speed difference was more caused by way fewer explored nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quadratically constrained problems are fundamentally more complicated than linearly constrained problems because the feasible set is not necessarily convex (unless, of course, you are specific about what kinds of constraints you allow).

To give just one example, consider the problem
$$
  \min_{x,y} -y \\
  \text{such that } -1 \le x \le 1 \\
  \qquad\qquad \quad 0 \le y \le x^2+1.
$$
If you plot the feasible set, you will see that it is not convex. Indeed, the problem has two solutions: $x=\pm 1, y=2$.

On the other hand, a convex quadratic objective function with linear constraints has only one solution, and it can be found using active set methods. These methods are not vastly more complex than the simplex algorithm for linear programs.

Comment: this example really nails down my question!